# How to interpret $-2^{x + 1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I was given this math problem on one of my assignments

$$1 = -2^{x + 1} +5$$

My question is regarding the negative on the $2$ (base) in the equation.

If I assume the $-2$ is $(-2)$, then the solution I would get is "no solution", which is the answer I wrote down on the assignment. If I assume $-1(2)$, then the answer I would get is $x = 1$, which is what my teacher says is the correct answer.

Are both solutions technically valid due to ambiguity? Or is there a clear rule stated that if a negative is not written inside a parenthesis, we have to assume the negative is a coefficient.

Comment: Look up PEMDAS. That's the order of operations. Exponents are before addition/subtraction. So in your equation it's $2^{x+1}$ before you change the sign.

Comment: Note that $-2^{x+1} \neq (-2)^{x+1}$. Super common mistake. Your problem utilizes the former, so you should exponentiate first and then multiply by $-1$.

Comment: In general, we do not say that an equation has multiple solutions *solely because* of an ambiguity. We might say that the equation has two (or more) interpretations, and depending on which interpretation we choose, it has a different set of solutions; in such cases, the right thing to do is to resolve the ambiguity in favor of one or the other interpretation.

Comment: In this case, there is not really any ambiguity—the equation is unquestionably equivalent to $1 = -\!\left(2^{x+1}\right)+5$. You were just unfamiliar, perhaps, with the convention regarding order of evaluation. But now you know!

Comment: It depends on the language.  On computers (Haskell, Microsoft Excel) $-1^x = (-1)^x$, but on informal publications $-1^x = -(1^x)$.  It's common for formal languages to have a rule that unary operators are always evaluated before binary operators.  In informal languages, it is common to prioritize being able to write polynomials easily.

Comment: Would you sketch $\quad y=-x^2\quad$ as a smiley or frowny curve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between $(-x)^2, -x^2$ and $-(x)^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142346/whats-the-difference-between-x2-x2-and-x2) and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907851/why-is-the-result-of-22-4-but-22-4